# ListView GroupHeaderTemplate with fixed height on iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to set a variable height list view on iOS. Our code (on the sample project linked and main part below) works fine on Droid, but fails miserably on iOS.
I have tried iOS 9.3 and iOS 10, with forms 2.3.2.127 and latest prerelease 2.3.3.163-pre3.

```
<ListView Grid.Row="2"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MenuSections}"
    IsGroupingEnabled="True"
    HasUnevenRows="True"
    SeparatorVisibility="Default"
    ItemTapped="ListViewOnItemTapped">

<ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
        <StackLayout Padding="15,10,15,10"
                     Spacing="0"
                     BackgroundColor="Green">
            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                    LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                    TextColor="White"
                    FontSize="14"/>

            <Label Text="{Binding Description}"
                    Margin="0,0,0,10"
                    IsVisible="{Binding HasDescription}"
                    LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                    TextColor="{StaticResource BSDirtyWhite}"
                    FontSize="11"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
```

I have already removed everything above with only a Label, and got exactly same result. Looks like header height on iOS is fixed to some constant number.

Please find below the screen shots for Droid (working fine) and failed iOS 9.3 and 10.

Any help or workaround is greatly appreciated.
CodeKnox

Droid perfect header:
[image: Droid perfect header:]

iOS 9 broken header:
[image: iOS 9 broken header]

iOS 10 broken header:
[image: iOS 10 broken header]

Sample project:
[repro xamarin forms project](https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=D96C7B6CE19A2F61&resid=D96C7B6CE19A2F61%21374735&authkey=AAabHi6haM6BNmk)

Comment: I've the same question o Xamarin Forum: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/80698/listview-groupheadertemplate-fixed-height-on-ios

Comment: This would seem to be a bug. I have filed a bug report here:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=45773

Answer (score 1):

This bug is tracked on the Xamarin Forms Github site: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3769

There is a gist in the comments suggesting creating a custom renderer:
https://gist.github.com/nbevans/a713dc9c77a8f530b6f4f3cd4fad83c2