# ListView GroupHeader item not set fixed height how to change Groupheader item values in xamarin forms

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

The code below works fine in Android, however in iOS it's not working as expected. The issue is that the height seems to be any alternative for this solution. Thanks in Advance.

```
<ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                                <Grid BackgroundColor="White" ColumnSpacing="5">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                       
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Label Text="{Binding Key.OperationId}" IsVisible="false"/>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Key.ImageUrl}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" WidthRequest="50"  HeightRequest="50" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Key.Description}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black" 
                                            VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontSize="15" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Key.Code}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontSize="15" />
                                </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
```

Comment: "not working as expected" and "issue in height" are not helpful descriptions of your problem.  Have you tried actually setting a HeightRequest value?

Comment: I have a two labels in the group header template in Listview but Grid I have set Auto in size for both, looks like statically not Auto in size grid

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40143384/listview-groupheadertemplate-with-fixed-height-on-ios same like this

Comment: don't use Auto, actually specify a Height value

Comment: Ok will check @Jason

Comment: Not working as expected if I specify height not expand item template data while tapping group header. Any renderer or any alternative fix for this issue? @Jason

Comment: Is my requirement Groupheader has two labels and one image while tapping to expand the radio button in the item template it's possible to achieve in Listview? Android working as expected but in IOS groupheader not working in height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This potential issue is being tracked on this thread: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3769

There is a gist in the comments suggesting creating a `custom renderer` to fix the ListView GroupHeader size in iOS: https://gist.github.com/nbevans/a713dc9c77a8f530b6f4f3cd4fad83c2

[Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69247600/9644964).

Comment: @Alexander May - MSFT above following GitHub link we can use an entire bunch renderer or any particular data only enough to fix these issues?

Comment: I believe you need use all the renderer. Also, you need to change the follow line(61):
`var cellView = innerWrapper.Subviews[0];`
to
`var cellView = innerWrapper.Subviews.LastODefault();`

Comment: @Alexander May - MSFT okay thanks let me check and let you know

Comment: @Alexander May - MSFT, Great it was working as expected

Comment: @Alexander May - MSFT, when tapped Groupheader  item based on item template can shown it can work on Android will expand and collapse but in ios only expand when again clicked it occupy empty space